# Getting error while deserializing an json Object

Tags: java, deserialization

I am having a json structure of

```
{"data":[{"name":"value"}]}
```

and my pojo class for this json is

```
public class RequestParamsDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2440599796986757919L;

    private Object name;


    public Object getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(Object fields) {
        this.name = fields;
    }
}
```

Here while deserializing this json throws error,I found that declaring Object as datatype leads to the issue,if I change it to string or Integer its worked,whether some one had this issue?

```
Reason for declared name as Object is
This name parameter will contain string or integer dynamically in run time,I have written an logic depands on it.
```

Comment: Try with 'String' and later convert to your desired type.

Comment: @ANyarThar I have internal logic of changing the functionality using the datatype of this parameter,some thing like instance of works.